# Getting error while posting in LinkedIn

Tags: ios, iphone, linkedin-api

I'm getting error Request failed: bad request (400) while trying to post in LInkedIn

Below is my code

```
-(IBAction)btnLinkedIdShareClicked:(id)sender{
NSString *stringRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:LINKED_IN_ACCESS_TOKEN]];

//Request parameter on a dictionary (keys in camel case)
NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"anyone",@"code",nil],  @"visibility",
                        @"TEST", @"comment",[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"description share", @"description", @"link_url", @"submittedUrl", @"title share",@"title", @"image_url",@"submittedImageUrl",nil], @"content",nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

[manager POST:stringRequest parameters:update success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id     responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"result: %@", responseObject);
//completionBlock(YES, responseObject, nil);
    NSLog(@"Yes");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"No");
}];
}
```

Thanks in advance, any solution to resolve this...?